# How can i hide fullscreen native button in iphone in video tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can i hide fullscreen native button in iphone in video tag using html css and jquery.
If i use controls in video tag then i wants to hide full screen button
This solution is not working anymore.

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this solution works till this date, I can confirm that. There is something else that is  wrong ...

Comment: @GAURAV - Were you able to find out a workaround?